# Is this the full o the half region?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, area

I need to find the area of the region bounded by four graphs : $z \geq 0$, $y=0$, $x^2+z^2=25$ and $y=2z$.

[image]
[image]
I don't understand if I should use the region red and yellow or only yellow.

On the other hand, I don't know how to obtain the function for the lateral part of the cylinder to calculate the area of ​​the cylindrical mantle.

Thanks!

surface in area y=2z [Surface 1]

\begin{align}
z=\frac{1}{2}y\\
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}y\\
f_x(x,y)=0\\
f_y(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\\
S_1=\int_r\int\sqrt{1+(\frac{1}{2})^2}dA\\
=\int_0^\pi\int_0^5 \sqrt5rdrd\theta\\
=\int_0^\pi\int_0^5\frac{\sqrt5}{2}r^2d\theta\\
=\frac{5}{2}25\pi \approx 87.81 u^2
\end{align}

[Surface 2]
\begin{align}
\int_0\pi \int_0^5\sqrt{1+0^2+0^2}rdrd\theta\\
S_2=\int_0^\pi \int_0^5\frac{1}{2}rdrd\theta\\
=\int_0^\pi\frac{r^2}{2}|_0^5 d\theta
=\frac{25}{2}\int_0^\pi d\theta\\
=\frac{25}{2}\pi \approx 39.27 u^2
\end{align}

[Surface 3]

\begin{align}
Since: z=\frac{y}{2}\\
x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=25 \Rightarrow y=4\sqrt{25-x^2}\\
0 \leq y \leq 4\sqrt{25-x^2}\\
And:\\
x^2+0=25 \Rightarrow x=\pm5\\
-5\leq x\leq5
\end{align}
Now:
\begin{align}
x^2+z^2=25 \Rightarrow f(x,y)=\sqrt{25-x^2}\\
f_x(x,y)=\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{25-x^2}}=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\\
f_y(x,y)=0\\
Replacing:
S_3=\int_R\int\sqrt{1+(\frac{-x}{\sqrt25-x^2})^2+0^2}dA\\
=5\int_R\int\frac{dA}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\\
= 5\int_-5^5\int_0^{4\sqrt25-x^2}\frac{1}{25-x^2}dydx\\
=10 \int_0^5\frac{1}{\sqrt25-x^2}(\int_0^4\sqrt{25-x^2}dy)dx\\
=40 \int_0^5dy=200 u^2
\end{align}

So the surface is $S_1+S_2+S_3=87.81u^2+39.27 u^2+200 u^2=327.8 u^2$

Comment: Is the red side negative $x$? If so, yes you have to consider it - both negative and positive $x$ have to be considered.

Comment: Thanks! Now my last problem is how obtain the function for the lateral part of the cylinder to calculate the area of ​​the cylindrical mantle. Can you give any hint please?

Comment: You have figured out how to find part of the surface area in $y = 2z$ plane? In any case, my suggestion is to always post your  working and where you get stuck. For cylinder's lateral surface, note it is $2 \pi \ r \ h$. In this case $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq y \leq 10  \sin \theta$. Here $y$ is height ($h$) and we are using parametrization $x = 5 \cos \theta, z = 5 \sin\theta$

Comment: I asked my professor and he told me not to use parametrization, but that the side of the cylinder is the graph of a function. And this function can be obtained from the equation of the cylinder. And then use the surface area formula. But I'm stuck in there

Comment: The function is $10 \sin \theta$

Comment: Also radius is $5$. So you have to integrate $50 \sin \theta$ over $[0, \pi]$

Comment: I think i solved it. I edited the original post with the answer, I would really appreciate if you could give me a comment :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126617/discussion-between-math-lover-and-delight).

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I'm in

Answer (score 1):

Surface $1$: while you get the correct answer, the working is not correct. You are taking projection in XY plane and integrating over a semi-circle but the projection in XY-plane is not a semi-circle as the cylinder equation is $x^2 + z^2 = 25$.

Also, you wrote $\displaystyle S_1=\iint \sqrt{1+(\frac{1}{2})^2} \ dA$

but in the next line, you removed $\dfrac{1}{2}$. Pls check.

Surface $3$: You write $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=25 \Rightarrow y=4\sqrt{25-x^2}$ but it should be $y = 2 \sqrt{25-x^2}$.

In any case, you should be using projection in $XZ$ plane (at least for $S_1$) as the cylinder is along y-axis.

Surface $1$:

$y = f(x, z) = 2z, f_x = 0, f_z = 2$.

So the integral is,

$\displaystyle S_1 = \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^5 r \sqrt{1+2^2} \ dr \ d\theta = \dfrac{25 \sqrt5 \pi}{2}$

Surface $2$: surface area $S_2$ is simply $\dfrac{25 \pi}{2}$

Surface $3$:

$x^2+z^2 = 25, 0 \leq y \leq 2z$. So,

$\displaystyle S_3 = \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{10 \sin \theta} 5  \ dy \ d\theta = 100$